# onDelete database trigger isn't being called

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have two cloud functions that negate each other, shown below:

```
    exports.onPostLiked = functions.database.ref('userpostlikescomments/{uid}/{pushId}/likes/list/{uid2}')
.onCreate(event => {
    //runs w/o error
    const numsRef = event.data.ref.parent.parent.child('num');
    numsRef.transaction(currentData => {
        return (currentData || 0) + 1;
    });
});

exports.onPostUnliked = functions.database.ref('userpostlikescomments/{uid}/{pushId}/likes/list/{uid2}')
.onDelete(event => {
    const numsRef = event.data.ref.parent.parent.child('num');
    numsRef.transaction(currentData => {
        return (currentData || 0) - 1;
    });
});
```

`onPostLiked` is called and works, however the `onPostUnliked` function doesn't get called at all when I delete something that was just created at the specified path. Why would this be the case?

I did the following to add and delete nodes:

[image]
I went to the desired node
[image]
I added another element to the list, the number of elements is updated
[image]
We can see the `onPostLiked` cloud function is called, note the time
[image]
then we delete the created node
[image]
`onPostUnLiked` doesn't get called, again note the time
[image]
the number of elements doesn't get updated

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that should trigger each function.  (Obviously, if the client code isn't doing the right thing, the function would never be invoked, but we have no way of seeing that here.)

Comment: i added and deleted nodes using the console

Comment: Then perhaps you could update your question with the steps you took at the console (with screenshots) that illustrate what you're doing.  If you feel there is an obvious reproducible error here, please feel free to file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I've updated the question, was there something I did wrong? Also, I'd like to add there is another function that works like this for a different path and it works just fine.

Comment: @JoelRobinson-Johnson try this path instead of the one that you already have `'userpostlikescomments/{uid}/{pushId}/likes/list/two'` in `onDelete()` and please inform me if it triggers to write it as an answer

Comment: `onPostUnliked` gets called when the path is changed

Comment: @JoelRobinson-Johnson okay great, I will add it as an answer but can you try this in your `onCreate()` `console.log("added data is", event.params.uid2);` and tell me what the output is also please

Comment: @PeterHaddad the console prints out "added data is two"

Comment: What version of the firebase-functions module are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Change the path in `onDelete()`, from this:

```
ref('userpostlikescomments/{uid}/{pushId}/likes/list/{uid2}')
```

to this:

```
ref('userpostlikescomments/{uid}/{pushId}/likes/list/two')
```

and it will get triggered when you delete the item.

Also it is better to use `console.log` to be able to log what is being added or on what path are you.

Comment: here's the thing, when a user adds a new node, a push id will be generated. I need a general path that can be useful in all cases

Comment: okay, you have `list` inside of it there is `one` and `two`, keep the path as in the question and remove `one` instead of `two` @JoelRobinson-Johnson

Comment: the number of elements does get updated if I do that

Comment: @JoelRobinson-Johnson okay I think if you add list=>a random pushid=>one:value=>two:value in the database it should work. Currently there is no pushid in the database. `one` and `two` are directly under `list`

Comment: I just changed the final wildcard from uid2 and uidnew and now it works, why don't know

Answer (score 0):

You could try using one trigger `onChange` for the given path, and check the actual kind of the event, for example:

```
exports.onPostLikeOrUnlike = functions.database.ref('userpostlikescomments/{uid}/{pushId}/likes/list/{uid2}')
.onChange(event => {
    if(event.data.previous.val() === null) {
        //There was no previous value in the db, thus execute onCreate functionality
    }

    if(event.data.val() === null) {
         //In this case, we know that there has been a previous value, but there is no current value, thus this execute onDelete functionality.        
    }

    //If the conditions above weren't true, that means we've previous and current values as well, so this is an onUpdate event.
});
```